# Does anyone know what a AsyncPageable is?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to do a get all from an Azure service and it returns an AsyncPageable. According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.asyncpageable-1?view=azure-dotnet) it says

> A collection of values that may take multiple service requests to iterate over.

Does that mean that it is equal to doing the request for a single item multiple times with a loop?

Comment: After reviewing the docs and everything, there is something not clear. Does a pageable return a page containing multiple items and if there are more items then another page is retrieved (internally making another request) and so on until all items are returned in the form of pages OR that happens when AsPages is used? If the second option is correct, what does the first do? or viceversa

Answer (score 18):

If a service call returns multiple values in pages it would return `Pageable<T>`/`AsyncPageable<T>` as a result. Check out [Consuming Service Methods Returning AsyncPageable](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Core/1.0.1/index.html).

*To get more clarity, have a look at below:
This shows control over receiving pages of values from the service use* `AsyncPageable<T>.AsPages` method:

```cs
// call a service method, which returns AsyncPageable<T>
AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> response = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync();

await foreach (Page<SecretProperties> page in response.AsPages())
{
    // enumerate through page items
    foreach (SecretProperties secretProperties in page.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(secretProperties.Name);
    }

    // get continuation token that can be used in AsPages call to resume enumeration
    Console.WriteLine(page.ContinuationToken);
}
```

*If your project doesn't have C# 8.0 enabled you can still iterate over AsyncPageable using a `while` loop:*

```cs
// call a service method, which returns AsyncPageable<T>
AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> response = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync();

IAsyncEnumerator<SecretProperties> enumerator = response.GetAsyncEnumerator();
try
{
    while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        SecretProperties secretProperties = enumerator.Current;
        Console.WriteLine(secretProperties.Name);
    }
}
finally
{
    await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Check out [Azure.Core Response samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/e0e1db5c7068efff57a415c8c56876f940f20163/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Response.md) to understand more about this.

To change page size, you can use `pageSizeHint` parameter to `AsPages` method.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, each page contains an n amount of items and a method that returns a pageable will make multiple gets, each returning one "page" until all the items are returned. If that is so, 1) How do I know how many items per page are returned? and  2)How can I modify that value?

Comment: Yes, you are right. For your second question, there is no method to control the number of results per page for this return type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.pageable-1?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Exploring the link you shared I could see that there is an AsPages method with an pageSizeHint parameter. Could that be used to modify a method to retrieve a certain amount of items?

Comment: Ahh, yes. That should work. But, it applies only to AsPages method. My bad.

Comment: After reviewing the docs and everything, there is something not clear. Does a pageable return a page containing multiple items and if there are more items then another page is retrieved (internally making another request) and so on until all items are returned in the form of pages OR that happens when AsPages is used? If the second option is correct, what does the first do? and viceversa.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.asyncpageable-1?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Works perfectly for Azure Storage blobs retriving. Thanks for adding the implementation for older C# versions!